# Passing extra data to Celery Task object

Tags: python, django, celery

I am having a simple task class:

```
class MyTask(Task):

    def run(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

I want to pass extra dict to task when I am executing it, but whenever I run:

```
task = MyTask()
ret = task.apply_async(args=(x, y), kwargs={'some_key':'some_value'}
```

I got an error:

```
TypeError: run() got multiple values for keyword argument 'some_key'
```

How to add extra data to task? I am running my tasks with big countdown and before adding new task I need to check list of all tasks and value I want to pass with kwargs is for filtering this list.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: don't user kwargs. just call using `some_key='some_value'`

Comment: or ```task.apply_async(*(x, y), **{'some_key':'some_value'})```